# Django: Admin site not assigning permission group to user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to add a user to an existing permission group using the Django admin site. The problem is, when I add the group to the user using the admin drop-down, the group is not assigned despite the UI showing that it is.

[image]
I can see the user has not actually been added to the group in the Django shell

```
>>> from api.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> user.groups.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

When I used the shell insead of the admin site to add the group to the user it works however

```
>>> from api.models import User
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

>>> group = Group.objects.get(name='System admin')
>>> user = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> user.groups.add(group)
>>> user.groups.all()
<QuerySet [<Group: System admin>]>
```

It is becoming tedious to edit permission groups for users using the shell. What are some reasons why the admin site is not properly assigning groups to users?

Comment: Looks like you have a custom user model, you have probably not configured the admin to use your custom user model instead of the built-in one

Comment: @IainShelvington I am indeed using a custom user model and can confirm it has been configured to replace the built-in-one since its forked from a previous project